# Overflow error during numerical integration

Tags: python

I'm using the [Python wrapper](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature) for the Cubature package to perform the following numerical integration:

```
from cubature import cubature
import numpy as np

fdim = 1
ndim = 1

def k0(k): 
    return np.sqrt(k**2 + M**2)

def I0(y0, y):
    return np.log((np.exp(y0+y)-1)/(np.exp(y0-y)-1))-y

def f(k):
    return I0(k0(k), k)/k**3

def new_f(x_array, *args, **kwargs):
    t = x_array
    return f(a+t/(1-t))*1/(1-t)**2

a = 10
M = 10

xmin = np.array([0])
xmax = np.array([1])
val, err = cubature(new_f, ndim, fdim, xmin, xmax, adaptive='h')

print(val, err)
```

The original integration of f(x) goes from 10 to infinity, but the substitution described [here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature_(Multi-dimensional_integration)) allows me to integrate f_new(t) from 0 to 1.

The problem is that I can't handle the precision when dealing with the exponential function, so I get the following error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
return np.log((np.exp(y0+y)-1)/(np.exp(y0-y)-1))-y
[inf] [nan]
```

Any suggestions? I really need to learn how to deal with these types of integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to deal with this issue was to rewrite the function a bit, such that we avoid large numbers, as suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659125/returning-inf-when-finite-result-is-expected) in the context of C++.