# Returning 'inf' when finite result is expected

Tags: c++

The outputs are not what Python/Mathematica previously calculated when calling `test_func(3000, 10)`. Instead, my code returns `inf`, and I am not sure why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

//I0
double I0 (double y0, double y)
{
    return(
        log ( (exp(y0+y)-1)/(exp(y0-y)-1) ) - y
        );
}

//test_func
double test_func (double k, double M)
{
    double k0 = sqrt(pow(k, 2.0)+pow(M, 2.0));
    cout << "k0: " << k0 << endl;
    double Izero = I0(k0, k);
    cout << "I0: " << Izero << endl;
    double k3 = pow(k, 3.0);
    cout << "k3: " << k3 << endl;
    return(
        Izero/k3
        );
}

int main ()
{
    cout << test_func(3000, 10) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
k0: 3000.02
I0: inf
k3: 2.7e+10
inf
```

but `I0` should be `3004.1026690762033`, while the result of the function should be `test_func(3000, 10)=1.1126306181763716e-07`. I am puzzled. Do you know what is wrong with it? I am a C++ beginner, so any help is very welcome.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code posted so far has no `main` function and does not attempt to output the result of the function

Comment: your numerator of your log in the ```IO``` function ```(exp(y0+y)-1)``` exceeds the limits of a double in C++. Change all of your ```double``` to ```long double``` as it will allow you to work with larger numbers.

Comment: Looks like your `exp(y0+y)` simply overflows (`y0+y~=6004`). The `inf` then propagates (`inf`/finite = `inf` and so on)

Comment: Suggestion: When something goes wrong in a statement, break the statement up. Then you can step through it bit by bit easily or print out the results of the stages to help narrow down where things went south.

Comment: exp(6000) is something on the order of 10^4000 whereas DBL_MAX typically 10^308

Comment: it might be time to use an infinite precision library for these calculations, rather than native floating types

Comment: @M.M this is one of my very first C++ codes, so could you please give me a reference about this library? I need to perform a lot of calculations like this toy example, so it sounds like a good plan.

Comment: @NeonFire `long double` doesn't necessarily have higher precision than `double`. Lots of platforms have `sizeof(long double) == sizeof(double)`

Comment: Please also read about [numerical stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability). I would not expect accurate results from a formula that looks like this, regardless of the machine's ability to represent the numbers.

Comment: also instead of `exp(y0+y)-1` you should use [`expm1(y0 + y)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/expm1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` has a limited range. On most modern implementations, `double`s are in the standard IEEE floating point `binary64` format, with range up to about `1.8e308`. Anything bigger (such as your `exp(6000)`) rounds up to infinity.

Switching to a larger type like `long double` may not be the best idea. Though the range of floating point types roughly grows exponentially with size, the fact that you use the `exp` function makes it easy to defeat the extra precision. E.g. on an implementation with 80-bit `long double` (with range up to about `1.2e4932`), modifying `test_func` and `I0` to use `long double` still fails to evaluate `test_func(5700, 10)`.

It is instead possible to redesign `I0` to avoid huge numbers. Let's start by splitting the `log`.

```
double I0(double y0, double y) {
    return log(exp(y0+y)-1) - log(exp(y0-y)-1) - y;
}
```

When you're computing `log(exp(y0+y) - 1)`, if `exp(y0+y)` gives infinity you can recover the computation by using `y0+y` instead of the `log`. I.e. we're ignoring the `-1`, because if our numbers are that large the precision of `double` isn't enough to actually register the difference in the final result. Also, you may want to replace both `exp(x) - 1`s with `expm1`. This is because when `x` is close to `0`, `exp(x) - 1` will tend to lose precision. E.g. `exp(1e-16) - 1 == 0` but `expm1(1e-16) > 0` assuming IEEE. I suspect that's not as important to you.

```
double I0(double y0, double y) {
    double num = expm1(y0 + y), den = expm1(y0 - y);
    num = isinf(num) ? y0 + y : log(num);
    den = isinf(den) ? y0 - y : log(den); // though I suspect the domain of I0 is such that you don't actually need this
    return num - den - y;
}
```

This is only a very rudimentary correction. Squeezing the most correctness out of floating point is very difficult in general and is its own whole field of programming. However, this is enough to make your case work, and even works on those large inputs where the naive `long double` also fails. (I'm no expert, but I also notice that `y0-y` is itself problematic, since `y0` is apparently chosen to be close to `y`. Subtraction between them loses precision that may (or may not) destroy the result.)

If you don't want to deal with rewriting your formulas to fit within the limitations of floating point (completely understandable, given the potential for bugs!), I would suggest following @M.M's advice and using an arbitrary-precision math library like MPFR. That's similar to replacing `double` with `long double`, but now you can keep throwing bits at the problems until they go away whereas you will eventually run out of built-in floating point types.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Answer suitably pedantified.

Comment: Thank you so much, @HTNW, for such a detailed explanation. It makes a lot of sense now. However, even though this is a toy example, my real implementation requires `y0` to be close to `y` in some cases; in fact, this function `I0` will be numerically integrated, and a certain relation constrains the pair (y0, y). I was reading about MPFR, but this is one of my very first C++ codes, so I would be greatly thankful if you could give me an idea about the implementation (or a reference).

Comment: in GCC you can use [`__float128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html) to get quaduple-precision if you don't need arbitrary precision

Comment: @surrutiaquir I can't help with MPFR as I haven't used it myself, sorry. The official manual seems a good reference though. You might use one of the C++ wrappers listed on the website as it's a C library. (IMO while using a wrapper would be good long-term, if you're in a rush using MPFR directly may save you many headaches.) As for `y0-y`, *if* there is a problem, perhaps find a formula for `I0` in terms of just `y` and `d = y0 - y`, and then find a way to calculate `d` without the subtraction. But don't do it blindly: look for the places where precision is lost and fix them as they come.